# Where to store profile images for android application like whatsapp?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm creating a android chat application with a basic layout and hosted in a php hosting service and mysql as my back end.  I'm retrieving the user details using JSON from server to update my user lists. Now these are my issues regarding profile pics

1. But now I wanna store profile image of the user. I really have no idea of storing profile pics. Becoz other people have mentioned that storing image in the mysql table would bring down the performance of the db system. Which is efficient way to do this?
2. While retrieving image (weather it is in mysql or server), I don't want to load profile pics each time. What can be done for this issue ?

Comment: 2) You can check, if android does not have the pic it will search the pic on server.

Comment: 1)You can save it on server or on db. On server will be a little more useful, but how much space you've got? Are you sure you can store all those images? You need to think that too.

Comment: I think there is only limited amount of storage in the server as there is only 120 users. @MarcoMura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on the same project once

1 - The best way to store profile pictures is to do it like Viber and Whatsapp store them in the internal memory or external if there is any available space of course

2- well you need to cache your photos once loaded the first time and then just load them from the cached version if there is any modification then you apply the new photo in place of the cached one and cache it again

[EDIT]

After your comment I understand that you're using mysql to store chat messages and profile pictures, so you can go this way :

you store the images in the mysql database within your server and for every user you download his friends pictures then cache and store them in the sdcard.

for every new user you ask him to upload his picture to your database then his friends will download it back.

Comment: You're second answer gives me idea about after stage of 1st question. Thanks to that. But in 1st one,Where I've to store that's my problem really, after storing in internal memory/external memory of the user's device, how will the other user's can get the image.

Comment: @Arun your welcome just Edited with proposition

Comment: This is the solution i just needed, simple and efficient for small size application like mine. But still curious about, what would be ideal for a large scale app. And i'm looking fr the guy who put -1 for my question, Coz i'm a guy who is still learning, if you're not helping just leave. There are other people to do something called "help". Just wanna say it.

Comment: Hi Arun glad I helped don't worry keep learning and asking good luck on your projects